# Check varbinary type not is null and download it

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have created a table in which there is one column of type `varbinary(max)` to store the files.
What I want to do is that I want to show a pictureBox if that column is not null nad I  have written this code:

```
private void ViewSentMailDet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picturebox.Visible = false;
    string con_string = @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=fyp;Integrated Security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
    string qry = "select file from sentmail where msg_id='"+id of a particular row+"'";
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (dr["file"] != null)
            picturebox.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

But still its showing the pictureBox on load event of this page even if the file column is null.

Furthermore I want to download this particular file from the table to a disc when the user clicks on the pictureBox.

Comment: where are you setting the image of the picturebox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the major rules of using any kind of database is never return data you don't need. With this in mind you should exclude rows with no image using the query rather than checking after the fact.

So:

```
"select file from sentmail where msg_id='"+id of a particular row+"' and file is not null"
```

Rather than:

```
if (dr["file"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    picturebox.Visible = true;
}
```

Giving us:

```
private void ViewSentMailDet_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    picturebox.Visible = false;
    string con_string = @"Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=fyp;Integrated Security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
    string qry = "select file from sentmail where msg_id='"+id of a particular row+"' and file is not null";
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ad.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dr["file"])) 
            picturebox.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        picturebox.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dr["file"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    picturebox.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, can you please provide some commentary and a comment about what is wrong in the OP's post.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the column contains binary data or null, you can use

```
    if(!dr.IsNull("attach"))
    {
        attachment.Visible = true;
    }
```

Get image bytes

> `Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dr["attach"];`

Convert image bytes to image

```
Image image = null;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Show the picture on the picturebox

> `picturebox.Image = image;`

To save the image, on picturebox.Click event handler

> `picturebox.Image.Save(@"drive:/path/to/save/image.bmp");`

---

*Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer if you found it helpful.*